# Access returned values in backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In my backbone code, I'm getting the returned value to a variable and now I have to access one particular value with that variable.

Following is the returned value from the server

```
Object {
    readyState = 4, 
    responseText = '{"analysis":{"created_a...s"],"status":"active"}}', 
    status = 201, 
    more...
}
```

This is how I get the above result in console

```
attributes = {
    locale: $action.find('#locale').val(),
    title: $action.find('#title').val(),
    category: $action.find('#category').val(),
    status: $action.find('#analysis_status').val(),
    matrix: $action.find('#analysis_matrix').val(),
    predefined_barriers: barrierTexts,
    features: featureTexts
}

b = this.model.save(attributes);
```

What I want is to access the `responseText`

How can I access it with the variable `b` or is there any other good way to do it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`save` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) returns the [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) that is returned by the internally used [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), so you can just add a callback to it as usual:

```
this.model.save(attributes).done(function(data) {
    // you could use
    this.responseText
    // but you probably will use the already parsed JSON
    data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an asynchronous call, so it will have to be a callback.  You can pass a `success` callback to `save` --

```
b = this.model.save(attributes, { success: function(model, response) {

    console.log(b.responseText);
} });
```